# Translating a piece of C++ to Python

Tags: c++, python

I'm trying to convert some C++ to Python.

The C++ can be found at

https://gist.github.com/1635288

```
from prime import prime
from fractions import gcd
from copy import copy
def phi(n, primes):
    if n < 2:
        return 0

    if n in primes:
        return n - 1

    if (n & 1) == 0:
        m = n >> 1
        #return ~(m & 1) ? phi(m, primes) << 1 : phi(m, primes)
        if ~(m & 1):
            return phi(m, primes) << 1
        else:
            return phi(m, primes)

    for i in primes:
        if i > n:
            break

        if n % i:
            continue

        m = copy(i)
        o = n / m
        d = gcd(m, o)
        #return d == 1 ? phi(m) * phi(o) : phi(m) * phi(o) * d / phi(d)
        if d == 1:
            return phi(m, primes) * phi(o, primes)
        else:
            return phi(m, primes) * phi(o, primes) * d / phi(d, primes)

primes = []
for i in range(3, 10000000, 2):
    if prime(i):
        primes.append(i)

for i in range(80, 90): # a test to see if I am getting correct results
    print phi(i, primes)
    # returns   64, 54, 80, 82, 48, 64, 84, 56, 80, 88
    # should be 32, 54, 40, 82, 24, 64, 42, 56, 40, 88
```

Basically, the function returns correct phi values for odd n, but returns double the correct value for even n. I suspect that where I am going wrong is at

```
m = copy(i)
```

whereas the C++ is

```
int m = *p;
```

I have looked up Wikipedia and seen that this is defining m as the value p is *pointing* to. Is this the problem? If not, what is?

Comment: `p` is an iterator. `*p` is the value of the position in the vector that the iterator is currently set to. You don't need to `copy` a primitive type variable - just use `for m in primes:`. You also don't need to pass `primes` around.

Comment: by the way, instead of writing the `print` test, you can easily use the `doctest` module and write `python -m doctest phy.py` (cfr http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html)

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: there are no primitive types in Python. Everything is an object. If by "primitive" you meant builtin objects then there are mutable builtin objects such as lists, dicts, sets. It happens integers are immutable in Python so copy() is unnecessary here.

Comment: if `primes` is a list then `n in primes` is a O(len(primes)) operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `if not (m & 1)`, rather that `if ~(m & 1)`, since the former is a check for odd/even numbers, while the latter would only return `false` if you pass -1 to it.

Tilde (`~`) is the bitwise negation operator. For integer values it holds that `~x == -x-1`, which in your case won't happen at all.

Comment: -1 is not an issue here - we are dealing with the set of natural numbers only

Comment: @nebffa exactly. So your check for ~(m & 1) will **always** return `true`, which makes little sense.

Comment: Lol - derp by me. Just tried it out (sorry, takes a little running time with the range of numbers I am using) and it works. I'm sorry I doubted you, fellow Python jedi Qnan. Quick q - does (m & 1) return the AND of (first bit of m, 1)?

Comment: @nebffa it's a bitwise AND operation, yes, so `m & 1` is `1` for any odd number and `0` for an even one.

Comment: what I mean is - does it perform an & on every bit in m, or just the first bit in M. I'm assuming it just does it on that first bit? Or is a better explanation/example: 7 & 1 = 0111 & 1 = 0111 & 0001 = 0001 which we then say is 1

Comment: @nebffa I think you latter explanation is correct, for example (7 & 2) == (0111 & 0010) would be 0010, or 2.

Comment: Yes I just tested - 10 & 3 = 1010 & 0011 = 0010 = 2. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

`int m = *p` actually calls `operator*` of `p`, which is an iterator. It will return the integer that the iterator is currently on. For the given C++ code this is just syntactic sugaring (with a little bit of performance improvement), to avoid writing `*p*` every time.

Comment: Ok so then my translation into Python would be correct then, yes? Hmm what is my problem with the algorithm..